# Pasting Charts from Excel to PowerPoint

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm trying to paste charts from Excel to PowerPoint using VBA using the below but I'm unable to get this working. Could anyone please help me out here?

```
cht.Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteDefault).Select
```

however, what's stumping is that I'm able to paste just fine with the below which pastes the charts as images so I'm presuming the line is correct?

```
cht.Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture).Select
```

*I'm currently using excel 2016.*

Comment: .Select selects an object. Where is the rest of your code? Look at some of the many related answers to this question e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492519/paste-excel-chart-into-powerpoint-using-vba   or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35072513/vba-copy-paste-selected-charts-from-excel-to-powerpoint  or......

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paste Excel Chart into Powerpoint using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492519/paste-excel-chart-into-powerpoint-using-vba)

Comment: I've added the rest of the code now!I've had a look at the link but not sure how to modify the paste section to paste into a chart rather then a image - can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: For starters you need to reference the PowerPoint presentation which means you need an instance of PowerPoint application as well.

Comment: Do you get an error, or does it just not work? If you get an error, what's the error, and which line is highlighted?

Comment: I have code that uses nominally the same syntax, except there's no `.Select`: Instead I reference the pasted object using `activeSlide.Shapes(activeSlide.Shapes.Count)`.