# Repositioning Excel Charts as I add them into the same powerpoint slide

Tags: python-3.x, excel, powerpoint, win32com

I am using Python3 and the win32com package to automatically copy charts from an excel file and paste them into a powerpoint presentation. The charts do not all fit on one slide unless they are resized, so I scale their width by 0.85. However, I am not sure how to paste them at specific locations so they are all pasted atop one another. I think I have found a solution in visual basic (here: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-positioning-chart-in-powerpoint-after-copy-pasting-from-excel.1107603/ and here: [VBA: Copy + Paste Selected Charts from Excel to Powerpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35072513/vba-copy-paste-selected-charts-from-excel-to-powerpoint)) but I don't know any VBA so am not sure how to translate it to python. Thank you for your help!

```
import os
import win32com.client as client
from win32com.client import constants        

xl = client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
ppt = client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('PowerPoint.Application')

wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath("desiredFile.xlsx"))
prs = ppt.Presentations.Open(os.path.abspath("sample00.pptx"))

sheet = wb.Sheets('TheSheetINeed')


Slide = prs.Slides.Add(prs.Slides.Count,constants.ppLayoutBlank)

for ch in sheet.ChartObjects():
 ch.Activate()
 ch.Copy()
    
 Slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(constants.ppPasteShape).ScaleWidth(.85,0)
#Here is where I need help
    
prs.Save()
prs.Close()   
wb.Close(False)

ppt.Quit()
xl.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Python3 declares variables or otherwise works, but I would try something like the following. Instead of

```
Slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(constants.ppPasteShape).ScaleWidth(.85,0)
```

I would try

```
shp = Slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(constants.ppPasteShape).ScaleWidth(.85,0)
shp.Left = LeftValue
shp.Top = TopValue
```

where shp is a variable that represents the pasted shape.

Comment: Thank you, this worked: For anyone who stumbles on this post, the python syntax was:
shp = Slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(constants.ppPasteShape)
shp.ScaleWidth(.85,0)
shp.Left = xcoord
shp.Top = ycoord

and I used a loop to iterate through the desired values for xcoord and ycoord